# Command button to open file - file path located in the same cell button is aligned to

Tags: vba, excel, button

I'm trying to get a single macro that I can assign to my command buttons. I have multiple buttons that open different files so in each cell I include a different file path.

Currently my command buttons are looking for a specific cell reference and opening that value.
Is there any way I can get the macro to look for the value in the cell to which it is aligned?

I'm using two macros at the moment - one to create the buttons and then another to assign to the buttons. I am having to create a new macro for each button.

Macro to create button...

Sub Buttons()

```
Dim i As Long
Dim lRow2 As Integer
Dim shp As Object
Dim dblLeft As Double
Dim dblTop As Double
Dim dblWidth As Double
Dim dblHeight As Double

With Sheets("Print Schedule")
    dblLeft = .Columns("A:A").Left      'All buttons have same Left position
    dblWidth = .Columns("A:A").Width    'All buttons have same Width

        For i = Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) To ActiveCell + 15
        dblHeight = .Rows(i).Height     'Set Height to height of row
        dblTop = .Rows(i).Top           'Set Top top of row
        Set shp = .Buttons.Add(dblLeft, dblTop, dblWidth, dblHeight)
        shp.Characters.Text = "Open Print Schedule"
        Next i
End With
```

End Sub

Macros to open file...

```
Sub Mendip()
Dim myfile As String

myfile = Cells(6, 6).Value

Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfile
End Sub
```

Please tell me there is a better way to do this!

Comment: You can Assign a common macro to button and use Application.Caller to find the cell address

Answer (score 3):

When you create the form buttons as shown below then you can assign a common macro to them

[image]

And you can assign a macro like this

[image]

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim shp As Shape

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)

    'MsgBox shp.TopLeftCell.Address

    Select Case shp.TopLeftCell.Address
        Case "$A$1"
            '~~> Do Something
        Case "$B$1"
            '~~> Do Something

        '
        '~~> And So on
        '
    End Select
End Sub
```

**EDIT**:

One thing I forgot to mention. To assign the "Sample" macro to all buttons, Add the below line after you create the shape.

```
shp.OnAction = "Sample"
```

Comment: This is a really helpful answer and a great way to start - unfortunately I know very little about the Case function. Can you explain it a bit more for me?

Comment: Thank you - I'll look through the search results to find an effective explanation.