# Building the correct path for followhyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

## BIG PICTURE

1. Go through a list and create a tab for each item in the list (Working)
2. Create a hyperlink in the list that links to the associated worksheet (Working)
3. Create basic header information on each worksheet and hyperlink back to index sheet (Working)
4. Insert a button for each reference listed in a corresponding cell in the index sheet (working)
5. Add hyperlink to button click that opens pdf, doc, or docx file (Not working, work in progress)

## CURRENT PROBLEM

Depending on the button name, the file will be stored in 1 of 3 directories. While the button name is a unique part of the filename, there may be to the file name and the extension can vary between doc and docx.

I have three button name formats

```
F-1010
F-0400-01
928
```

In the first case I can generate the exact full filename exactly as the files will all be `F-1010.pdf` format

[image: Directory capture]

In the second case the file name will start with button name and be followed by additional text and then a variation in word document extension: `F-0400-01 abc def.doc` or `F-0400-01 abc def.docx`

[image: Directory capture]

In the third case the file name will start with `OPSS` folled by sometimes some text followed by the button name followed by a bunch of text and end with .pdf: `OPSS 928 abc.pdf` or `OPSS.MUNI 928 abc.pdf`

[image: directory capture]

I tried using wildcards in the string but that is not working.

```
Sub btnClick()

Dim btnName As String
Dim FPath As String
    
    'btnName = Application.Caller
    btnName = "F-0400-01" 'assigned name for testing purposes
        If Left(btnName, 1) = "F" Then
            If Num_Characters_In_String(btnName, "-") = 2 Then
                FPath = "P:\2019\1234 Folder\08. Working\Specifications\Section F" & btnName & "*.doc*"
            Else
                FPath = "P:\2019\1234 Folder\10. Construction\01. Tender\F\" & btnName & ".pdf"
            End If
        Else
            FPath = "P:\2019\1234 Folder\10. Construction\01. Tender\OPSS\OPSS*" & btnName & "*.pdf"
        End If
    
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink FPath
   
End Sub
```

Error for second and third case

[image: error msg]

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620769/command-button-to-open-file-file-path-located-in-the-same-cell-button-is-align) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185260/open-a-pdf-using-vba-in-excel) to get me where I am

## QUESTION

**How do I properly build the path? How do I open the various file types?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860797/how-do-i-open-a-file-if-i-only-know-part-of-the-file-name) and used the function solution by Rex.

I had a problem at the end of the function though with the transpose part giving me an error of type mismatch. so I modified the code as follows:

```
Sub btnClick()

Dim btnName As String
Dim FPath As String
Dim basePath As String
Dim sLink As String

    basePath = "P:\2019\1234 Folder"
    'btnName = Application.Caller
    btnName = "180"
        If Left(btnName, 1) = "F" Then
            If Num_Characters_In_String(btnName, "-") = 2 Then
                FPath = basePath & "\08. Working\Specifications\Section F\"
            Else
                FPath = basePath & "\10. Construction\01. Tender\F\"
            End If
        Else
            FPath = basePath & "\10. Construction\01. Tender\OPSS\"
        End If
    sLink = fileName(FPath, "*" & btnName & "*", ".*")
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink sLink
   
End Sub
```

and the modified filename sub as follows:

```
Function fileName(path As String, sName As String, ext As String) As String

'path is Full path from root.  Can also use path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\"
'sName is the string to search. ? and * are wildcards.  ? is for single char
'example sName = "book?" or sName ="March_*_2014*"
'ext is file extention ie .pdf .xlsm .xls? .j*

Dim file As Variant 'Store the next result of Dir
Dim fname() As String 'Dynamic Array for result set
ReDim fname(0 To 0)
Dim i As Integer ' Counter
i = 0

' Use dir to search and store first result
fname(i) = path & Dir(path & "\" & sName & ext)
i = i + 1

'Load next result
file = Dir

While file <> "" 'While a file is found store that file in the array
  ReDim Preserve fname(0 To i) As String
  fname(i) = path & file
  file = Dir
Wend

'fileName = Application.Transpose(fname) 'Print out array
fileName = fname(0)
End Function
```